# Jupyter Notebook is not loaded

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I followed the document: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook

and was able to enabled the component gateway of Jupyter, however, I didn't get the directory page of the jupyter as it mentioned in the document.

screenshot:

[image: to open jupyter]

the URL it opens:
XXXdataproc.googleusercontent.com/gateway/default/jupyter/tree?

screenshot:
[image: the console has no error, but Jupyter is not loaded]

Comment: What is the version of the image (including the sub-minor version) you used to create the cluster? There was an issue with the component gateway but it should have been resolved now. I just tried the Jupyter tutorial and was able to see the notebook page on a 1.3.45-debian9 cluster. So can you retry the steps from the tutorial?